# GraphQL Resolver - Multiple Promises

Tags: node.js, promise, graphql

I'm currently trying to call multiple Rest data sources to pull back a combined set of users in a single graph.

When running the query via Graphql Playground I'm getting null values which would point to the resolver function.

Looking in the debug console I can see that I'm getting data returned but I've got an additional layer of nesting includes which would explain why I'm not seeing the data in Graphql playground.

Resolver function looks like this:

```
    latestProspects: async (_, __, { dataSources }) => {

        try { 

          return Promise.all([
            dataSources.site1Prospects.getLatestProspects(),
            dataSources.site2Prospects.getLatestProspects()
          ])

        } catch(error) { 
          console.log(error)
        }

      },
```

**UPDATE**

Thinking things through I realise that the result sets are held in a dimension per data source.

I've updated my code to merge the two result sets together, not sure I'm able to improve things further?

```
type Prospect {
    date_created_gmt: String
    first_name: String
    last_name: String
    email: String
    billing: Address
    meta_data: [Metadata]
}

latestProspects: async (_, __, { dataSources }) => {


        try { 

          return await Promise.all([
            dataSources.site1Prospects.getLatestProspects(),
            dataSources.site2Prospects.getLatestProspects()
          ])
          .then(result => {

             const prospects = result[0]
             
             return prospects.concat(result[1])
             
          })


        } catch(error) { 
          console.log(error)
        }

      },
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information here to really help you.

Comment: My issue was mainly to do with the result sets being stored in separate dimensions per datasource.

Comment: Please show us your graphql schema definitions (i.e. what should the resolver return) as well as the implementation(s) or return values of the `getLatestProspects()` method(s)

Comment: @user1387363 If you're saying you already solved the problem, you may consider deleting the question